# Add array of controls to an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, controls

I'm trying to add an array of controls to an aspx page (C# code behind).  These are the similar controls (search criteria for separate fields but will have the same values).  The dropdown control values are currently set in the Page_Load method, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ListItem[] items = new ListItem[3];
  //these values are actually set by a database query
  items[0] = new ListItem('Apple', 'Apple');
  items[1] = new ListItem('Orange', 'Orange');
  items[2] = new ListItem('Banana', 'Banana');

  FruitDropDown.Items.AddRange(items);
  FruitDropDown.DataBind();
}
```

then on the page I have a control like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="FruitDropDown" runat="server"/>
```

This works fine and populates the control, but I want to now create an array of those dropdowns - there will be 20 of them, so I don't want to create it 20 times in the Page_Load method.  Should I add the dropdown population in a list and then do something like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="FruitDropDown[0]" runat="server"/>
<asp:DropDownList ID="FruitDropDown[1]" runat="server"/>
```

How would I label them on the page and then be able to access those values in the controller?  Could I do something like this if I've already added those named controls to the aspx page?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ListItem[] items = new ListItem[3];
  //these values are actually set by a database query
  items[0] = new ListItem('Apple', 'Apple');
  items[1] = new ListItem('Orange', 'Orange');
  items[2] = new ListItem('Banana', 'Banana');

  for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
    FruitDropDown[x].Items.AddRange(items);
    FruitDropDown[x].DataBind();
}
```

Does this also require copying and pasting the controls on the aspx page 20 times?  What if it expands to 100?  Can I add those in a loop on the aspx page?

Answer (score 4):

[Control.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx) is what you're looking for. You can use it on any Control(like Page itself) to find controls via their [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx). Put them e.g. in a Panel and use FindControl on it.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
    DropDownList ddlFruit = (DropDownList)FruitPanel.FindControl("FruitDropDown" + x);
    ddlFruit.Items.AddRange(items[x]);    
}
```

You can also create them dynamically:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
   DropDownList ddlFruit = new DropDownList();
   ddlFruit.ID = "FruitDropDown" + x
   ddlFruit.Items.AddRange(items[x]);  
   FruitPanel.Controls.Add(ddlFruit); 
}
```

You must recreate dynamically created controls on every postback at the latest in Page_Load with the same ID as before to ensure that ViewState is loaded correctly and events are triggered.

Comment: If I do the FindControl, will I have to create those controls 20 times on the page itself? Can that be done in a loop to minimize copied code?

Comment: You can use `FindControls` also on dynamically created controls. But as you can see in my example, you can do both in one loop without findcontrol because you already have a reference of the newly created control there.

Comment: If I use the second example to create them dynamically, I understand they will be added to the FruitPanel control on the aspx page. However, how does this handle positioning and layout? I want to create a few dynamic textboxes/dropdowns and added them in a single row. How will I control the layout by just calling the add method? Do I have to set the position manually? I could add 20 controls to the page, but that seems like a bad way to do it - how could I add those in a loop on the page to keep the layout consistent?

Comment: The positioning and layout of the FruitPanel should be controlled by CSS just as for the DropDownList. If you need more control over the layout of each DropDown you should show us a model, then you maybe should use other Container controls like [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) or [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) what makes also the dynamic  creation of the controls redundant.

Answer (score 3):

You can give them valid IDs and put them all in an array yourself:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="FruitDropDown0" runat="server"/>
<asp:DropDownList ID="FruitDropDown1" runat="server"/>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   ListItem[] items = new ListItem[3];
   ...

   DropDownList[] lists = new DropDownList[] { FruitDropDown0
                                              ,FruitDropDown1
                                              ,...};

   foreach(DropDownList list in lists) {
      list.Items.AddRange(items);
      list.DataBind();
   }
}
```

Comment: So do I have to cut and paste the <asp:DropDownList ID="FruitDropDown0" runat="server"/> line 20 times (or more) and increment the counter in the ID? Can I create that in a loop on the page so I don't have to maintain copied code?

Answer (score 1):

From your question it looks like you are trying dynamically render controls on the screen

[Here is a good article on doing this.](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133936/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082102-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into dynamically creating controls.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317794

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mark Cidade says your best approach would be to create the controls in the code behind.  They are just classes after all.

The simplest approach would be to put a control such as a placeHolder control on in the markup and then create a collection of dropdown lists in a loop, assinging each one a unique id like @Mark Cidade says.

From there it's a matter of adding them as child controls to the placeHolder or if you want them directly on the page you can add them to the page controls collection.