# How do you get the ID of a control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I am attempting to loop through an array of numbers, match them to the checkbox they they are associated with, and checkmark that box.

My checkbox is set up like:

```
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="someID" name="somename" value="1234" />
```

My code when the page loads currently looks like:

```
foreach (string interest in interests_Var){
   foreach (var c in Page.Controls)
   {
   }
}
```

`interests_Var` is my array containing different numbers.  We'll assume one of them is `1234`.  While looping through the page controls, I want to compare the value of the control to my number.  If it equals my number, I want to then apply the attribute `checked="checked"`.  I'm assuming I have to find the ID of the control I am using, then use that ID to add a new attribute.  Or is there a way I can add the attribute using the `c` variable?

I'm not dead set on this setup, so if you know a better way, I'm all ears.  Thanks for any help and suggestions.

**Thanks**

Lots of good suggestions.  I will try these in a bit.  Got side-tracked on another project.

**Solved**

Ok, so here's my end code.  Thanks for the help James.

```
foreach (string interest in interests_Var)
{
       foreach (var chkCtrl in Panel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
       {
           if (chkCtrl.Attributes["value"].ToString() == interest.ToString())
          {
               chkCtrl.Checked = true;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: How nested your destination control can be ?

Comment: View source and look at what the input tag renders as the id.  There are many ways to customize and control this.

Comment: You could use Page.FindControl method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx) instead of looping through each control on the page.

Comment: What is happening? Are you finding the checkboxes?

Comment: Is it inside a DataBound Control ?

Comment: @scott It renders with the long generated ID for the content control with my ID at the end.

Comment: @KevRitchie Well my issue would be that I do not know the ID's.  Though I suppose I could make the ID's whatever the value is...

Comment: @PankajGarg No, it is not a databound control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be best served putting the CheckBox controls into a `Panel` or a `PlaceHolder`, because then you won't have to worry about recursive logic to traverse the control hierarchy.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Testing" value="1234" />
    ...
</asp:Panel>
```

By putting the controls into a container, you can just loop through the child controls of that element:

```
foreach (string interest in interests_Var)
{
    foreach (var chkCtrl in Panel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
    {
        chkCtrl.Checked = chkCtrl.Attributes["value"].Contains(interest.ToString());
    }
}
```

Assuming `interests_Var` is a `List`, here's a shorter way to do it using LINQ:

```
interests_Var.ForEach(str => plcInvoiceDetail.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
    .Select(chk => chk.Checked = chk.Attributes["value"] == str));
```

Comment: I personally prefer using `PlaceHolder`, because it doesn't add any extra markup tags to the page like `Panel` does. `Panel` wraps everything in a `<div>`.

Comment: I tried this, but I cannot use the asp checkbox control it seems.  It does not allow a value to be set (?) as I've searched in the generated code, and even when I moved the value to the name field and search on the name attribute, it seems that is puts the name attribute in a span tag and wraps the checkbox inside of that.  Of course, I did try to run it both ways anyway, but neither worked.  No errors, though.  Want me to post my new code?

Comment: @James: Intellisense doesn't pick it up, but you should still be able to set the value attribute.

Comment: Yes, I just did `Response.Write(chkCtrl.Attributes["value"].ToString());` and it does print out all of the values.  But it seems it's not checking the boxes still.

Comment: Maybe try `chk.Checked = chk.Attributes["value"].Contains(str)` instead?

Comment: @JamesJohnson I'm not sure what you mean.  Isn't that what you had me try to begin with?  Other than it seems you've changed the variable name from chkCtrl to chk.  I do have `interest.ToString()` in the `Contains` brackets, though.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the LINQ example. You're not using a `CheckBoxList` for this by any chance, are you?

Comment: No, I'm not using that.  But I was still able to use this with small changes.  I'll post my fix in my original post.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using multiple checkboxes and have multiple values stored.
It is best to use the Asp:Checkbox, rather thatn simply assigning the runat="server" attribute to your input-control.

Let's assume you have a datasource like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public String Name {get;set;}
   public int Number {get;set;}
}
```

Use this server-control:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblMyList" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Number">
```

The `Name` property will be used as a displaystring, where as the `Number` is the value that actually is part of the HTTP Post.

In the OnInit-Eventhandler you would probably bind like this:

```
List<MyClass> values = //...
cblMyList.DataSource = values;
cblMyList.DataBind();
foreach (ListItem item in this.cblMyList.Items)
{
   if(interests.Contains(item.Value))
   {
    item.Selected = true;
   }
}
```

Getting all selected values would be done with this piece of code:

```
List<int> selectedValues = cblMyList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value)).ToList();
```

I chose int as the datatype for the DataValueField. Of course you can use other types, just replace the `int` with the datatype of your choice.

Comment: I don't actually have a data source.  The values are hard coded into the input elements.  The thing is, I have an array of interests that someone has chosen previously, and need to check mark the boxes they belong to.  So I want to loop through each checkbox to see if it has the value of the interest number, and if it does, check it.

Answer (score 2):

If you assign your check boxes an ID like "interest" + `value`, then you can use `FindControl` to look up your check box by interest:

```
foreach (string interest in interests_Var)
{
    HtmlInputCheckBox checkBox = (HtmlInputCheckBox)this.FindControl("interest" + interest);
    if (checkBox == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing check box for " + interest);
    checkBox.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: You should probably make sure you found one before trying to check it.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: Thanks for the suggestion. Since it's probably a bug if the check box can't be found, I throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a Web Forms app, and you aren't dead set on doing it how you described, you can change your markup to this instead:

```
<asp:CheckBox id="someID" runat="server" />
```

Then it will be defined in the .designer.cs file. That way, you can simply reference it in your code like this:

```
if ( someID.Checked )
{
    // do whatever
}
```

Note that if it is a control that is dynamically added, you'll still have to use the `FindControl()` method mentioned by others, because Visual Studio won't have added it to the .designer.cs file for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Array of Controls as described at the following articles:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21159/How-to-Create-a-Control-Array-in-C

For traversing values from the controls you may use the following for reference:-

[Add array of controls to an aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746513/add-array-of-controls-to-an-aspx-page)


And I would recommend you to use ASP.NET Checkbox instead of HTML  < input type="checkbox">.