# Add multiple controls to asp Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I'm attempting to add a group of controls to a page when a button is clicked. I need to add the same group of controls multiple times, possibly infinite times.  Currently the add controls button click works, it's when you click it the 2nd, 3rd, 4th...etc, time that it doesn't work properly.  It's overriding and replacing the controls that are currently on the page, so only one group of controls is ever shown.

this is my code that creates and adds the controls, this happens in a click event

```
        Label contactTypeLabel = new Label();
        contactTypeLabel.Text = "Contact Type" + contactCount.ToString();
        contactTypeLabel.ID = "contactLabel" + contactCount.ToString();
        this.panelContacts.Controls.Add(contactTypeLabel);
        DropDownList contactTypeDropDownList = new DropDownList();
        //loading dropdown
        this.panelContacts.Controls.Add(contactTypeDropDownList);
        this.panelContacts.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
```

this is the panel my controls are being added to..

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateContacts" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="panelContacts" runat="server">

                    </asp:Panel>

                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddContacts" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**What I ended up doing was using jQuery to create/remove the controls.  Works much better and easier!**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add array of controls to an aspx page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746513/add-array-of-controls-to-an-aspx-page)

Comment: is that why i'm downvoted and not just closed..

Comment: there is no selected answer for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746513/add-array-of-controls-to-an-aspx-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a repeater would be your best bet.

http://xaeryan.blogspot.ca/2009/09/dynamically-adding-removing-textboxes.html

it allows your for dynamically adding new rows of whatever asp.net controls you need.

hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

In every postback that happens when you click the button is recreating your page. 
You must keep the state of the page, by adding the controls in a list or something similar in session or viewstate.

So when pageload happens, you can add the controls again.

Answer (score -1):

You need to learn how ASP.NET works. This is not a bug or similar, it's just that you don't know how it works. Every time the page loads you have to add all those controls. You need to add those who where there before, and the "new" one as well. You need to keep some state somehow